# Python pyserial threading feature behavior

Tags: python, multithreading, pyserial

I am trying to get the python pyserial module threading feature to start a parallel thread that reads serial console messages and returns them. While that thread runs, I would like to do other things in the main thread. I created the following code snippet to try this out.

```
import serial
import serial.threaded
import time
import threading

PORT = 'loop://'

def monitor_bmc_console():
    class TestLines(serial.threaded.LineReader):
        def __init__(self):
            super(TestLines, self).__init__()
            self.received_lines = []

        def handle_line(self, data):
            self.received_lines.append(data)

    ser = serial.serial_for_url(PORT, baudrate=115200, timeout=1)
    with serial.threaded.ReaderThread(ser, TestLines) as protocol:
        while True:
            protocol.write_line('hello')
            time.sleep(2)
            print(protocol.received_lines)


x = threading.Thread(target = monitor_bmc_console(), daemon=True)
x.start()

while True:
    print('inside main thread')
    time.sleep(1)
```

In the output, I expect to see a stream of `inside main thread` printed in parallel with a continuous stream of `hello`. But this is what I see:

```
['hello']
['hello', 'hello']
['hello', 'hello', 'hello']
['hello', 'hello', 'hello', 'hello']
```

The message `inside main thread` DOES NOT get printed.
Can someone help me to determine what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You never start the `Thread` you call `x`. You meant to write: `x = threading.Thread(target = monitor_bmc_console, daemon=True)`. Now this will return the thread and `x.start()` will be called to start the thread.

Comment: `target=monitor_bmc_console()` _calls_ the `monitor_bmc_console` function, and then sets the new thread's `target` to whatever is returned by the function call. Only, in your case, that function never returns, so your program never even completes the call to `threading.Thread(...)`. Do what quamrana said if you want `monitor_bmc_console` to be called _in the new thread._

Comment: Yes. I changed `target=monitor_bmc_console()` to just `target=monitor_bmc_console` and it fixed the issue.